# Halacha B'Iyun Learning Help

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation

Where can I get hold of a semicha program syllabus or a guide to help me learn halacha b'iyun? I am not looking to learn for semicha just yet but want something to help be focus my halacha seder as just stam learning through shulchan aruch/rambam/mishna brura is getting a bit stale.  Ideally looking for a syllabus to help give breadth and depth e.g. the Israeli Rabbanut semicha.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites) Shmuel

Comment: Clever username +1

Answer (score 10):

Are you aware of a program called [**Tzurba M'Rabanan**](http://www.tzurba.com/)? It is a *halakha b'iyun* program to learn most of *Shulchan Aruch* over 4 years. They publish [brochures](http://www.tzurba.com/store.aspx) (or [a complete set](http://www.tzurba.com/buyProduct.aspx?id=541)) - each brochure contains material for approximately 8 weeks of learning (with one in-depth topic per week).

Each week covers a topic and brings 30-40 sources, from *gemara*, *rishonim*, *aharonim* to elucidate the topic in depth together with summary notes from R Ben Tzion Elgazi who prepared the material.

This is studied weekly in over 300 places all over Israel and is now expanding to a program for [youth](http://www.tzurba.com/showpage.aspx?pageid=589) and one for [women](https://kerendanielle.org/en/activity/tzorba-for-women/).

There is now an English translation as well, see [here](https://www.tzurbaolami.com/) for details.

Answer (score 5):

R. Yitzchak Berkowitz' Jerusalem Kollel has source sheets available online for a range of halachic topics. You can find them [here](http://www.thejerusalemkollel.com/online_classes.php) (in the column headed Level III).

They contain references to the relevant sources (starting from the gemara and rishonim and leading on to shulchan aruch and nosei keilim), as well as brief explanations and summaries.

I've personally used some of them before (on Issur v'Heter and Niddah) and found that they provide a good overview of the topic with a significant amount of depth.

Answer (score 1):

The Dirshu Mishnah Berurah is good - it has a compilation of the differnt machloksen by all the halachos and that sort of thing. They also have a good program for learning it.

https://dafhalacha.com/