# A sefer that states the reasons behind the Halachos

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books

Is there a sefer that states the Halachos L'maseah  and gives the reasoning as to why the Halacha is the way it is. 
I'm looking for a Halacha sefer that states the Halacha as we pasken, but also traces the Halacha back to its sources in the Gemarra.

Comment: What kind of reasoning are you looking for? “We are commanded to observe the Shabbos because it says שמור את יום השבת לקדשו,” or “We are commanded to observe the Shabbos the same way that Hashem rested after creating the world,” or...? However deep of a reason you get, there’s always one deeper.

Comment: The Svara for the Halacha...

Comment: That's a really broad term. What kind of logic are you looking for?

Comment: Halchos with the reasoning. I don't understand what's so broad. @DonielF

Comment: What kind of reasoning? The basic source for the obligation? The basic reasoning for it? The deeper reasoning for it? The kabbalistic meaning of it?

Comment: The Basic reasoning. The reasoning based of the Gemara. @DonielF

Comment: "Is there a sefer that states all the Halachos L'maseah": no. If there were, there'd be no need for asking your rabbi anything, and there'd be no responsa.

Comment: @msh210 Not "all". But a solid amount. Basically a Shulchan Aruch with the Sevaras...

Comment: Tzurbah Mrabanan is exactly what you looking for...i think

Comment: From their website,or contact them directly ,I ordered mine from Israel. http://store.tzurba.com/product.htm?id=2

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/87250/halacha-biyun-learning-help/87252#87252

Comment: If English is preferred, note there is now a translation of Tzurba D Rabbanan which started, see [here](https://mizrachi.org/tzurba/) for details

Answer (score 5):

[Sefer Hachinuch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sefer_ha-Chinuch) lists the 613 *mitzvot* with their rationale

> The Sefer ha-Chinuch systematically discusses the 613 commandments of
>   the Torah. It was published anonymously in 13th-century Spain. The
>   book separately discusses each of the 613 commandments, both from a
>   legal and a moral perspective. For each, the Chinuch's discussion
>   starts by linking the mitzvah to its Biblical source, and then
>   addresses the philosophical underpinnings of the commandment (here,
>   termed the "shoresh", or "root"). Following this, the Chinuch presents
>   a brief overview of the halakha (practical Jewish law) governing its
>   observance - usually based on Maimonides' Mishneh Torah - and closes
>   with a summary as to the commandment's applicability.

It is available in translation on [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_HaChinukh%2C_Author's_Introduction?lang=bi) or in print from [ArtScroll](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781422611890.html).

Comment: Did the question ask for _mitzvot_ from the Torah in particular?

Comment: ARBAA TURIM IS ALSO VERY GOOD